# Parse remote JSON without creating models in Swift, in a single function

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

My app must fetch JSON via HTTPS request, and then parse that data.

What I'm looking for is to have a "one function rules all" approach to it, like so.

```
func call(endpoint: String) {
   let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/api/"+endpoint)

   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
      // Parse JSON here without using a model.
      // Just convert the data into a JSON object and return it
   }
}
```

Every single example code I've come across seems to me that you need to make a model with the expected values, and then do this:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(ModelHere.self, from: data)
```

This means that I need to make a new function for each endpoint.

**Why not just use a separate function for each endpoint?**

I have a lot of endpoints that could be called from within a function.

Creating a new function for each endpoint to pass it a separate model to then parse the data from the response ... that is a lot of junk to sift through in the code.

I'm sure there is a better way to do it that is just obscure, or I'm missing.

Essentially, I'm looking for this:

a function needs remote data to load a view -> fires call('endpoint/example/') -> call() returns the json object -> the function can now take the data it needs

Multiple processor functions, one call() function. I hope I'm making sense.

Thanks

Comment: Please don’t add the accepted answer to your question, it is only confusing. We can all see what answer you have accepted and it won’t go away.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The answer, by the authors own admission, was not tested and could not work in its original form - hence the reason I added the *modified, working* answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what `generic` is for, for instance:

You can define `T` as a your date model which is a generic type, and you fetch it and return it with completion. Making `T` as codable so any model that conforms `codable` will make this call.

```
func call<T: Codable>(endpoint: String, completion: (T) -> ()) {
   let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/api/"+endpoint)

   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
      // Parse JSON here without using a model.
      // Just convert the data into a JSON object and return it
      let model = JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
      completion(model)
   }
}
```

And when you call the function:

```
call(endpoint: "something") { model: ModelHere in 
   // Use your model
}
```

So you don't have to make separate functions for every model you have.

** Code not been tested, just as an idea

EDIT: Here is an example with feedback from comment (Thank you @Leo)

```
private var host = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
    
enum NetworkError: Error {
    case invalidUrl
    case invalidData
    case underlying(_ error: Error)
}

func call<T: Decodable>(endpoint: String,
                        completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkError>) -> ()) -> Bool
{
    guard let url = URL(string: host+endpoint) else {
        completion(.failure(.invalidUrl))
        return false
    }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            return completion(.failure(.invalidData))
        }
        do {
            let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(.success(model))
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(.failure(.underlying(error)))
        }
    }.resume()
    return true
}
```

And when you call the functions:

```
struct SampleModel: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let content: String
}

func sample() {
    let isSuccess = call(endpoint: "fetchSampleModelUrl") { (result: Result<[SampleModel], NetworkError>) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let model):
            print("\(model)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks. I'll leave the final code in original post in case anyone needs it.

Comment: You can make it less restrictive using Decodable instead. Btw  `model: ModelHere` should be inside parentheses AFAIR and completion handler should be escaping.

Comment: I would also return a Result instead of the model and propagate the errors (url session/decoding)